# Dice-rolling Android app

Tags: java, android, animation, dice

This is just a simple app. All it's suppose to do is move the dice around the screen when the user swipes up or down. It will move 2 dice (image drawables) to a position on the screen depending whether they swiped up or down.

How can I make my code so it's more object-oriented? At the moment it isn't.

#### Main.java

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final int[] die = {R.drawable.die1,      R.drawable.die2,R.drawable.die3,R.drawable.die4,
                        R.drawable.die5, R.drawable.die6};
    float x1,x2;
    float y1, y2;
    public static ImageView dice1;
    public static ImageView dice2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dice1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die1);
        dice2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die2);
    }




    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
    {
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
            // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                x1 = touchevent.getX();
                y1 = touchevent.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                x2 = touchevent.getX();
                y2 = touchevent.getY();

                //if left to right sweep event on screen
                if (x1 < x2)
                { /*Not implemented yet*/ }

                // if right to left sweep event on screen
                if (x1 > x2)
                { /*Not implemented yet*/ }

                // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
                if (y1 < y2)
                {
                    //Swipe down:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Swiped Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    dice diceCall = new dice(1, dice1, dice2);
                    diceCall.swipe();
                }

                //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
                if (y1 > y2)
                {
                    //Swipe up:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Swiped Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    dice diceCall = new dice(2, dice1, dice2);
                    dice.swipe();

                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

### Dice.java

This class holds the animation events. In the constructor, type = 1 is for swiped DOWN and 2 for swiped UP.

```
public class dice {
    private static int type;
    private static ImageView die1;
    private static ImageView die2;


    public dice(int type, ImageView die1, ImageView die2) {
        this.type = type;
        this.die1 = die1;
        this.die2 = die2;
    }

    public static void swipe() {

        if(type == 1){
            animateTile();
            moveDiceOnSwipeDown();
        } else if(type == 2){
            moveDiceOnSwipeUp();
        }
        //Swipe right:

    }

    public static void animateTile(){

        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 310f, 17f, 11f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(700);


        die1.startAnimation(anim);
        die2.startAnimation(anim);

    }

    //Move dice from x to yy | Dice down
    public static void moveDiceOnSwipeDown(){

        //Die1
        TranslateAnimation moveDie1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 200);  //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        moveDie1.setDuration(2000);  // animation duration

        //Die2
        TranslateAnimation moveDie2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -100, 0, 400);
        moveDie2.setDuration(2000);
        moveDie1.setFillAfter(true);
        moveDie2.setFillAfter(true);

        //Start the animations
        die1.startAnimation(moveDie1);  // start animation
        die2.startAnimation(moveDie2);  // start animation
    }

    //Move dice UP
    public static void moveDiceOnSwipeUp(){

        //Die1
        TranslateAnimation moveDie1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -100, 0, -200);  //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        moveDie1.setDuration(2000);  // animation duration

        //Die2
        TranslateAnimation moveDie2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -180, 0, -400);
        moveDie2.setDuration(2000);
        moveDie1.setFillAfter(true);
        moveDie2.setFillAfter(true);


        //Start the animations
        die1.startAnimation(moveDie1);  // start animation
        die2.startAnimation(moveDie2);  // start animation

    }

}
```